# Find table name and its column name by column value (data's)

Tags: mysql

Is there any possibility of getting a table name and its column name's by passing a column `value(data)` that is nothing but a data. passing a value to get the table name and the column name's.

Comment: I am confused why this would ever need to happen

Comment: Why this should work?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility?

Yes, of course. You can use the MySQL's `information_schema` to retrieve names of tables and columns in the current database.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()
   AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'text')
```

You can use that result set to write a program, in php or Java, or your favorite language, that will search every column of every table.

You didn't ask if this is a good idea.  But I will answer anyway. No.